# Trying to install library 'quantmod' in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to download library 'quantmod' in R:

```
install.packages("quantmod")
```

console:

```
The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/RtmpwSKGIl/downloaded_packages’
```

then:

```
library("quantmod", lib.loc="/tmp/RtmpwSKGIl/downloaded_packages")
```

console:

```
Error in library("quantmod", lib.loc = "/tmp/RtmpwSKGIl/downloaded_packages") : 
  there is no package called ‘quantmod’
```

What is the problem?

Comment: just use `library(quantmod)`, that directory is just the location of the source code, not the package. (that should be somewhat similar to '.../R/win-library/3.3/package-name')

Comment: @AK88 the path doesn't look like very windowy to me. This line with "The downloaded packages..." is just to tell you where temporary downloaded files reside. This will be deleted on the next cleaning spree.

Comment: yeah, googling revealed that it wasn't a Windows machine...

Comment: GGamba@ when I try command library(quantmod) I have Error in library(quantmod) : there is no package called ‘quantmod’...

Comment: maybe you need to give details (R version, OS, ...)

Comment: @edouard - Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela, R version latest

Comment: did you have any error message and/or warning while install quantmod?

Comment: @edouard after install.packages("quantmod") I see in the console: Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘quantmod’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/RtmpE1W1Of/downloaded_packages’

Comment: isn't there a GCC-related warning message?

Comment: using this solution solved for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49360403/installation-of-quantmod-in-r

Answer (score 0):

I get no problem when I try to load this package.
Have you tried to provide R the full name path to your package file directory ?
C:/Users/...
Is your R version up to date ? Try to check if you have the latest, I tried and it worked with :

> R 3.3.3

If you are a Windows or MAC user you might want to force the download of the package from source to binary, this can be done by setting the right options in the install.packages command:

> options(install.packages.check.source = "no")

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/install.packages.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am a year late, but just got out of this situation by installing the Package from R (instead of RStudio) by changing the CRAN.
You can then run library(quantmod) in Rstudio. Hope this works(worked?) for you too.
I am ready to go now!